# how to align textview to center bottom of image

Tags: android, android-studio

how do you align a `textview` to the center of a image? Please see photo for easier understanding:

[image: 1]

I want `textview` "Blade Runner 2049" to be align to the center of blade runner image

I have tried `center gravity` and padding but both doesn't work... Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT:** This was the old xml for this question in case google brings anyone here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnFrozen"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBtnKin"
        android:background="@drawable/frozen_poster"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnHotelT"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBtnBladeRunner"
        android:background="@drawable/hotel_transylvania_3_poster"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnBladeRunner"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blade_runner_poster"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnKin"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/kin_poster"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBladeRunner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtnBladeRunner"
        android:text="Blade Runner 2049 "
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It would be great if you add XML of your layout too.

Comment: You should use RecyclerView or GridView and construct an item containing the image and text to achieve that. Try googling an example.

Comment: Please share your XML layout design, without that answering this question will be difficult.

Comment: You can review the answer, that should work

Answer (score 2):

You should use RecyclerView/GridView to obtain that layout. For each item in the RecyclerView/GridView try this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/poster" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Dunkirk"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will result in this layout (for each item in your RecyclerView/GridView):

[image: item layout]

More, if there are long titles you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- find a good ratio for the poster -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="229dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:src="@drawable/poster" />

    <!-- adjust maxWidth according to your poster ratio -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Very long title that will need to be split."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will result in this:

[image: item layout]

**Extra:** Go through [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started) tutorial for GridView. Or [this](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html) for RecyclerView.

Comment: this answer is good but not the one i was looking for, thanks for answering though

Comment: @wolnavi you can adapt what you need according to this answer. As I can see, you've got 4 image buttons, so you can wrap each of them like I did if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

set this inside of gridview

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearbot1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgvw_mon1"
                    android:layout_width="29dp"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_mon1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_mon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imgvw_mon1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="sample"
                    android:textColor="#e6e5e5"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

**PS:** you can also use this tutorial [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you I did not see your layout XML:

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_user_icon" /> // your image

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movieName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Blade Runner 2049" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your output you can use **RelativeLayout**.
Below is the sample code which will work in your case:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/tsp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/image"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Blade Runner 2049" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't work like it should. The TextView is not visible because the ImageView overloads it.

Comment: Thanks, @grrigore I have made changes in my code. Now Textview will be visible.

Comment: Yes, it will, but the children in the FrameLayout work like a stack, so TextView will be now over the ImageView, but adding `layout_gravity` to the TextView will center it in its parent (here the FrameLayout), so you won't get the layout that the OP wants. You'll get the image (let's say as a background) with the centered text over it. FrameLayout it's used for a single child, or more than one only if you want the children to overlay. Have a read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout). That's why you should use LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout.

Comment: I read the question again and I see that he formulated it quite wrong, but follow the picture. So your answer is good, but not what he really wants..

Comment: Yes, you are right that is why I have centered the image as well in its parent and this layout can be used in the adapter to achieve the output.

Comment: Yep, got your point. made the changes in code. Thanks @grrigore

Answer (score 0):

For those who are wondering how to solve it, I used @Krishna Sharma's answer and @Neeraj vishwakarma's answer but modified it a little bit, by adding in

```
android:layout_alignStart="@id/imgBtnFrozen"
```

to `TextView`, this is because if i do not do it, the `TextView` will just align itself to the screen's horizontal center (although it is still below the `ImageButton`)

Thanks to everyone for answering, your answers are great too